# How to checkin list of divs if there is a span within with class 'new'

Tags: python, list, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

In Beautifulsoup i receive a list of `divs`. Each of these divs has an `span` included:

```
<div role="news_item" class="ni_nav_9tg">
   <span class="nav_element_new_S5g">Germany vs. Japan</span>
</div>
...
<div role="news_item" class="ni_nav_9tg">
   <span class="nav_element_new_S5g">Brasil vs. Serbia</span>
</div>
```

What i want is to check if in this list of `div` a `span` exist whose `class` contains string "new". Just `true` or `false` as result.

Of course i could iterate through each item `div` in list and get `span` item after this check if `class` contains string "new", but i am not sure if this is the right approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could select them directly like:

```
soup.select('div[role="news_item"]:has(span[class*="new"])')
```

to get `True` or `False` check the `len()` of the `ResultSet`:

```
len(soup.select('div[role="news_item"]:has(span[class*="new"])')) > 0
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='''
<div role="news_item" class="ni_nav_9tg">
   <span class="nav_element_new_S5g">Germany vs. Japan</span>
</div>
...
<div role="news_item" class="ni_nav_9tg">
   <span class="nav_element_new_S5g">Brasil vs. Serbia</span>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

len(soup.select('div[role="news_item"]:has(span[class*="new"])')) > 0
```

Comment: Hm, i have implemented it as shown above, but i receive a `NotImplementedError: Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type.`